What would be the cause of a Brother color laser printing image ghosting?
Despite cleaning the corona wires and trying different papers, when printing large blocks of color on Brother HL-L3230CDW color laser printer, ghost artifacts can be seen approximately 30cm below. In the case of these large blocks, the ghost artifacts seem to only appear within the confines of that block.
The effect is especially evident if the paper is backlit (see image A here).

Importantly, the ghost artifacts don't seem to occur in blank/white places on the page.
For example, in the case of text, then there's no such ghosting 30cm below (see image B here).

The printer is almost three years old, and is often unplugged and unused for long periods of time. The storage environment is the entrance way to a Japanese apartment, which can get as cold as perhaps 12ºC in the winter, and as warm as almost 30ºC in the summer.
Would this problem persist if I replaced all of the toner units? Naturally, I don't want to buy new toner if the problem lies elsewhere, and is irreparable.
Printer Lifetime stats

Pages printed: 646 (550 color pages, 96 B&W pages)
Remaining Life Cycle Drum Unit Cyan (C): 97%
Remaining Life Cycle Drum Unit Magenta (M): 97%
Remaining Life Cycle Drum Unit Yellow (Y): 97%
Remaining Life Cycle Drum Unit Black (BK): 97%

Toner levels
C: 50%, M: 50%, Y: 50%, BK: 10%

could be the drum, but I'd look into other things too, such as if the paper used is als defined in the printer settings (also try different paper) and look into things as eco setting to see if a lighter print helps with the issue.

Try cleaning the corona wires - https://support.brother.com/g/s/id/htmldoc/printer/cv_hll3210cw/use/html/GUID-F0972AB4-CC3A-46B9-BB0C-F7039035A842_197.html

Thank you @LPChip. I've tried three different laser printer paper brands, all of them mid-to-high price range.
Thank you for your suggestion, re: eco settings.
I changed 'ECO' setting from OFF to ON.
I changed 'Toner Saver' setting from OFF to ON.
But the problem persists.

@davidgo I cleaned all of the corona wires, being sure to move slowly across. I did so 5 times per color. I'm afraid the problem persists. Thank you for your help.

The repeating factor tells me it is likely the drum. I would guess the repeating pattern matches the circumference of the drum.

I'm a little embarrassed to ask this follow-up question but I think I'm misunderstanding the parts of the printer. Two users have said, "the drum". But I thought there were four drums - one for each of C, M, Y, K. Is there a single, separate unit called 'the drum'?
If indeed there are four drums, then does it look like all of the drums separately have the same problem?

I bought a new genuine Brother replacement drum unit, swapped it with the old drum for cyan, making sure to follow directions perfectly (including cleaning the corona wire of the new drum). The print results were the same, with the ghosting effect.

I bought a new genuine cyan toner cartridge and inserted it into the new drum I bought. Did all of the correct things to do when installing a new cartridge, such as cleaning the corona wire. There is no change. I'm now giving up on this printer.
